# Como converter diferença de datas de segundos para horas/dias?

Tags: python, matemática

Eu fiz um programinha em python que ele pega a hora atual, a hora, converto em segundos e subtraio um do outro para saber qual a diferença entre ele.
Minha duvida é, como eu converto esses segundos para horas e dias?

Código que converto a data para segundos:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import time

date_now = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
date_created = time.mktime(get_demand_if_exist[0].date_created.timetuple())
diff_time = abs(date_now - date_created)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é o código que pede pro usuário o numero de segundos e apresenta em dias, horas, minutos e os segundos restantes.

Basta vc colocar sua saída em segundos no lugar da variável segundos e pronto.

Porém lembre-se de converter sua saída para inteiro.

```
segundos = int(input("Segundos: "))

dias = segundos // 86400
segundos_rest = segundos % 86400
horas = segundos_rest // 3600
segundos_rest = segundos_rest % 3600
minutos = segundos_rest // 60
segundos_rest = segundos_rest % 60

print(dias,"dias,",horas,"horas,",minutos,"minutos e",segundos_rest,"segundos.")
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava, pois eu precisava só calcular os dias/horas com os segundos que eu conseguia. Obrigado!

Comment: É melhor usar uma subtração d dois objeto `datetime`, que no Python cria um objto `timedelta` - veja a outra resposta. (O pacote `arrow` é desnecessário, na verdade). Esta resposta é boa se você já tem a diferneça de temo entre segundos - mas se tiver datas, o datetime do Python já vai contabilizar meses e anos com duração variável, etc...

Comment: @jsbueno,  Expliquei o uso do arrow nos cometarios da minha resposta, o meu exemplo seria dado sem o arrow, mas datetime exigiu que a primeira data do exemplo teria que ser "completa" (incluindo segundos), como eu não sei de onde viria a data que ele estava obtendo (database?) pensei no arrow para facilitar. Arrow é nota 10. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/KXON/1)*

A pergunta parece estar truncada, mas parece indicar que vc quer saber a diferença entre a data atual e a data de criação de alguma coisa, ou seja, a diferença entre duas datas:

### Arrow

```
$ pip install arrow
```

Criando as datas:

```
start = arrow.get(datetime.date(2017, 8, 16))
end = arrow.get(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Calculando o delta entre as duas:

```
td = end - start
```

Investigando o timedelta:

```
# Resultado
print (td)
7 days, 21:21:36.785675

# Número de dias:
print (td.days)
7

# Número de segundos
print (td.seconds)
76896

# Número de horas:
print (td.seconds/3600)
21.36

# Mais refinado (Número total de segundos)
td.total_seconds()
682433.962907
```

[Veja rodando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KXON/1)*

* Os resultados podem ser discrepantes se comparados com o código rodando em máquina local em função do fuso horário

Comment: Na verdade, o pacote  `arrow`  é desnecessário para os casos mais simples - subtrair um objeto datetime de outro diretamente produz um objeto  `timedelta` da mesma forma. O que o arrow faz é permitir aí é permitir a subtração entre um "datetime" e um "date" - se forem usados dois objetos `datetime` seu código mesmo funciona da mesma forma.

Comment: Sempre recomendo o Arrow pq ele falicita muuuito, principalmente para quem esta começando, criar um Delta sem ele pode se tornar um pesadelo para quem não tem intimidade com Datetime, nesse exemplo que eu dei ja nao funcionaria.

Comment: Aliás, eu ia dar o exemplo sem o arrow, mas desisti qdo vi a encrenca. :-)